# Oracle procedure to check if value starts from http or https

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-like

I'm using **IF** condition with '**NOT LIKE**' in my procedure to check if value starts from HTTP or HTTPS.
But if value starts from HTTP/HTTPS or not, then also for both cases it appends base URL.

Need suggestions to fix this.

```
if lower(l_value) NOT LIKE 'http://%' or lower(l_value) NOT LIKE 'https://%' then
      l_value := l_baseURL || l_value;
end if;
```

Comment: Please edit your question explain *what* issues you are facing. Sample values and expected results would also be helpful.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: Still, It is not clear what are you asking.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is just the `or`; that should be `and`:

```
if lower(l_value) NOT LIKE 'http://%' and lower(l_value) NOT LIKE 'https://%' then
      l_value := l_baseURL || l_value;
end if;
```

The same value can't match both conditions at the same time, so it if it does match one it still won't match the other; so your original `or` would always be true, for any value.

You could get the same effect by using `LIKE` and then negating the entire `or` condition:

```
if NOT (lower(l_value) LIKE 'http://%' or lower(l_value) LIKE 'https://%') then
      l_value := l_baseURL || l_value;
end if;
```

but I don't think that's any clearer really.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `AND` instead of `OR`

```
if lower(l_value) NOT LIKE 'http://%' and lower(l_value) NOT LIKE 'https://%' then
      l_value := l_baseURL || l_value;
end if;
```